# Why won't toilet flush after replacing wax ring?

Tags: plumbing

I'm not a professional plumber but I've replaced many wax rings before. The toilet worked perfectly fine before until I noticed a little leak at bottom of toilet. I replaced the worn out wax ring.

There are no more leaks but this time the water overflows and just won't have that swirling flush! Very slooow drain. There's no blockage, no leaks and I even replaced the wax ring a second time, just in case. I'm stumped! Just can't figure it out. Plunging, snaking and chemicals won't flush the toilet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did the toilet flush okay before replacing the wax ring?  How do you *know* there is no blockage?; the behavior is heavily consistent with a blockage.

Comment: If you replaced the wax ring and not just added another over the old one, maybe something fell in the toilet without notice and caused your trouble....

Comment: Did you verify that the tank-drain stopper is opening all the way (have to ask, sorry)?  If you pour a gallon sized bucket full of water into the bowl, does the draining increase (indicates problem is in between tank and drain) or decrease (possible venting issue), or stay the same (problem is clog in between bowl and drain, or in waste pipe)?

Answer (score 3):

Recheck the passage way that runs from the bowl to the horn. There must be an object lodge in there since the toilet flushed properly prior to the wax ring being replaced. Don't remove the toilet from the closet flange just yet. Insert a toilet auger and work the handle. It should advance through the toilet with little effort as it is being turned. If you encounter resistance reverse the auger while withdrawing it a short distance at the same time. Than continue pushing it forward feeling for any blockage. Withdraw the auger and flush to verify proper operation. If, after using the auger and flushing, the water doesn't flush pull the toilet, drain any standing water in the tank and bowl and lay it on its side on a plastic sheet. Examine the horn opening with a flashlight. If necessary insert a bent coat hanger into the opening and probe for foreign objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before. I used an OFF BRAND (Made in China) heavy duty extended wax ring from a hole in the wall, mom & pop hardware store/gas station. It had a thin layer of rubbery plastic through the interior of the plastic extension. That plastic came free at the bottom and sealed itself after 3 uses.

We tried an auger and a snake neither could bust it. One swift yank was all it took once the toilet was off.